# Enumeration may not execute exception when changing an independent variable

Tags: c#, exception, foreach, enumeration

I have been having an issue lately with a Foreach statement and it throwing an `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` exception when changing a variable that shouldn't impact the items being enumerated upon, but it still does. Here is my code so I can continue my explanation:

```
    private static CEconTradeOffer RemoveUndesirables(CEconTradeOffer offer)
    {
        try
        {
            CEconTradeOffer returned = offer;
            foreach (CEconAsset cEconAsset in offer.ItemsToReceive)
            {
                string marketHashName = cEconAsset.GetMarketHashName(_config.ApiKey);
                if (marketHashName.ToLower().Contains("case") ||
                    marketHashName.Contains("gut") ||
                    marketHashName.Contains("falchion") ||
                    marketHashName.Contains("bayonet") ||
                    marketHashName.Contains("huntsman") ||
                    marketHashName.Contains("karambit") ||
                    marketHashName.Contains("butterfly"))
                {
                    //somehow changes both "offer" and "returned" at once.
                    returned.ItemsToReceive.Remove(cEconAsset);
                    continue;
                }

                MarketValue value = MarketHandler.GetPriceOverview(Convert.ToUInt32(cEconAsset.AppId),
                    marketHashName);
                if (!value.Success || int.Parse(value.Volume, NumberStyles.AllowThousands) <= 20)
                    returned.ItemsToReceive.Remove(cEconAsset);
            }
            return returned;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Write.Exception(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This function was designed to do exactly what it says; remove undesired items from a trade offer. As you can see, I set `CEconTradeOffer returned` equal to the passed argument of the same type named `offer`. Strangely enough, whenever I change something inside of `returned` it causes the `foreach` statement to break even though I technically shouldn't be impacting `offer.ItemsToReceive` in any way. `returned` is what should be modified. When I use the debugger, I notice that BOTH `returned` and `offer` get changed at the line `returned.ItemsToReceive.Remove(cEconAsset);`. Through my previous experience with C# and browsing related problems, this should not be happening since I am creating a new variable that should be separate from `offer`. I have tried include setting `returned` equal to a `new CEconTradeOffer()` and then setting it equal to `offer` but to no avail. In my research of this problem, I can only seem to find problems where people fail to create a new variable and modifying that in the `foreach` statement rather than the enumerated value.

Is there something blatantly obvious I am missing? I do not quite understand why I am getting this particular issue when I create a separate variable to change inside the `foreach` statement.

I am not using more than one thread, so it can't be impacted outside of its own thread of execution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AlexD points out the problem in his answer below: `returned` IS `offer`, so the remove method modifies the collection and you get the error--don't modify a collection during enumeration.

Comment: Useful reading - [Shallow vs. Deep copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> whenever I change something inside of `returned` it causes the `foreach` statement to break even though I technically shouldn't be impacting `offer.ItemsToReceive` in any way.

It seems that `CEconTradeOffer` is a reference type, so then you assign

```
CEconTradeOffer returned = offer;
```

you get another reference to exactly the same thing.

So when the items are removed using `returned.ItemsToReceive.Remove(cEconAsset)` they are removed from the same collection, just via another reference.

Comment: I spotted it too but you got there first :P

Comment: Ah, okay. Is there a way to rectify this?

Comment: @ChrisAltig I did not check the logic. But if you want to modify a collection while enumerating it, you may use regular for loop. (If you delete items it may be easier to run from right to left, so removing items does not impact the rest.)

Comment: @AlexD I believe you are correct. My only other option is a deep copy which would slow down the program (not by much, but still). I find it strange that it is used as a reference rather than entirely new variable.